# Saving CLOS objects

Tags: printing, common-lisp, clos

Saving any Common Lisp structure object to a file (readably) seems relatively straightforward with something like

```
(defun save-structure-object (object filename)
  (with-open-file (stream filename :direction :output
                                   :if-exists :supersede)
    (with-standard-io-syntax (print object stream))))
```

For a CLOS object instance, however, the post at [Make clos objects printable in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086561/make-clos-objects-printable-in-lisp) indicates a more complex recipe.

First, does the comment about closer-mop relate to a simpler approach to saving a clos class instance?

And second, is the code offered there presented as a general utility for printing any clos instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Closer to MOP](https://github.com/pcostanza/closer-mop) allows one to avoid the dangerous tangle of read-time conditionals in the post you refer to.  Generally speaking, using an OOTB solution that many people use is safer than a random ad hoc hack - your own or someone else's.

Before `closer-mop` was around, I wrote my own [CLOS/MOP compatibility layer](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/src/port/mop.lisp) and [CLOS object i/o](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/src/cllib/closio.lisp). I suggest that you use it instead of the code in the SO answer you reference.

Comment: `closer-mop` is meant to replace only the `(defun get-slots ...)` part on that page, right? We still do need to set up reader macros, right?