# Installing CLOCC & packages

Tags: common-lisp, clos, clocc

The comment by sds at [Saving CLOS objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334222/saving-clos-objects/42334657#42334657) provides a reference to a Common Lisp Open Code Collection (CLOCC) file (closio.lisp) for printably reading & writing CLOS objects. Instructions for installing the software are at [Installation of CLOCC](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/INSTALL). However, not having previously used CLOCC, I would like some additional guidance in setting things up for reading/writing CLOS objects. Here are the additions to my init file (.clinit) so far:

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(setq *clocc-root* "D:\\clocc\\")
(load "D:\\clocc.fasl")
(load 
  (compile-file ;warns about |make|::COMPILED-FILE-P being undefined
    (translate-logical-pathname 
      "clocc:src;defsystem;defsystem")))
(dolist (s '("clocc:src;cllib;base" "clocc:src;port;sys"))
  (mk:add-registry-location (translate-logical-pathname s)))
```

Instructions for what to add next appreciated.

Comment: did you follow the instructions in the `INSTALL` file you link to step by step? you need to compile file using `mk:oos` and then load whatever files you need  and you are good to go.

Comment: The next two statements I've tried are
`(mk:oos "cllib" :compile)` and `(mk:oos "port" :compile)`
but they produce an error--e.g., Can't find system named "cllib". Also, tried `(mk:oos "src\\cllib")` where the directories are located, but same error.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions were obsolete. Sorry.

The [installation instructions](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/INSTALL) now say (I removed the systems you don't need):

```
(compile-file "c:/gnu/clocc/clocc") ; or whatever ...
(load *)
;; * load the defsystem facility
;; most lisps come with "asdf"; if this fails, get it yourself from
;; https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/
(require "asdf")

;; * compile some systems
(asdf:compile-system "port")
(asdf:compile-system "cllib")
...
```

You will need to follow the [asdf instructions](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/Configuring-ASDF-to-find-your-systems.html):

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/common-lisp/source-registry.conf.d/
$ echo '(:tree "c:/gnu/clocc/")' > asdf.conf
```

Comment: Doh, on to 2nd base (using Allegro CL). When compiling mop.lisp (in port), `slot-definition-initargs` is undefined function, with option to call `mop:slot-definition-initargs` instead. Doing so moves on to same error for `class-direct-slots`.

Comment: Looks like `port:mop` needs to be updated for the latest Allegro. We will need some back and forth on this. Please replace `:clos` with `:mop` on line 19 in `port:mop.lisp`. Does it work now?

Comment: Changing `:clos` to `:mop` on line 19 (for allegro) still produces same error for `slot-definition-initargs`. Continuing with `mop:slot-definition-initargs` instead, and after that with `mop:class-direct-slots`, then get Error: No methods applicable for generic function #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION MOP:SLOT-DEFINITION-INITARGS> with args (#<EXCL::STRUCTURE-DIRECT-SLOT-DEFINITION A @ #x21d65e52>) of classes (EXCL::STRUCTURE-DIRECT-SLOT-DEFINITION) [condition type: PROGRAM-ERROR].

Comment: This is weird. Please remove all compiled files and start from scratch. Thanks.

Comment: I went back and downloaded the clocc files again from https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/ (snapshot); extracted them to a new directory; ran thru each of the "Installation of CLOCC" steps again with no problems (except the MAKE::COMPILED-FILE-P undefined function warning); changed :clos to :mop in mop.lisp (line 19 only); but the exact same errors repeat when doing `(mk:oos "port" :compile)`. (ps: I'm using the "express" free version of Allegro CL, which has limited heap, but receive no message about over-running.)

Comment: I am sorry, please follow the new `asdf`-based instructions. They worked for me with Allegro and SBCL.

Comment: OK, bear with me please. I have `asdf` working with quicklisp libraries. For a clocc library, do I need to also install "ASDF-INSTALL" at https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf-install/tutorial/index-save.html ? (ps: on Windows 10)

Comment: No, just plain `asdf`, not `asdf-install`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136386/discussion-between-davypough-and-sds).